# How to get specific elements of from a webpage using beautifulsoup scrape in dart

Tags: html, web-scraping, flutter, dart

I have a website that I want to scrape and get specific data using dart for my flutter app, the problem is that I have 2 classes of the same name inside the webpage.I want to retrieve the

elements from within the second class but I am only reaching a place where I am creating a list of two elements that are the first and he second class.
here is the function that I am using to scrape:

```
Future episodelist() async {
  print('object');
 var response = await http.get('https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine');

 var soup =Beautifulsoup(response.body);
    print(soup.find_all(".check-list").map((e)=> (e.outerHtml)).toList());
    return soup.find_all(".check-list");

}
```

this is the main part that I want to scrape:

> 

```
                            <li>
                                <div class="epCheck ">
                                    <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197189" type="checkbox" id="check197189" >
                                    <label for="check197189"></label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-12">

                                    Hachigatsu no Cinderella Nine Episode 12

                                </a>
                                <br>
                                Released on 07 Jul, 2019
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <div class="epCheck ">
                                    <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197139" type="checkbox" id="check197139" >
                                    <label for="check197139"></label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-11">

                                    Hachigatsu no Cinderella Nine Episode 11

                                </a>
                                <br>
                                Released on 30 Jun, 2019
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <div class="epCheck ">
                                    <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197095" type="checkbox" id="check197095" >
                                    <label for="check197095"></label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-10">

                                    Hachigatsu no Cinderella Nine Episode 10

                                </a>
                                <br>
                                Released on 23 Jun, 2019
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <div class="epCheck ">
                                    <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197037" type="checkbox" id="check197037" >
                                    <label for="check197037"></label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-9">

                                    Hachigatsu no Cinderella Nine Episode 9

                                </a>
                                <br>
                                Released on 16 Jun, 2019
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <div class="epCheck ">
                                    <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196976" type="checkbox" id="check196976" >
                                    <label for="check196976"></label>
                                </div>
                                <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-8">

                                    Hachigatsu no Cinderella Nine Episode 8

                                </a>
                                <br>
                                Released on 10 Jun, 2019
                            </li>


                    </ul>
                    <!-- Check List -->


                </div>

                <!-- Tabber Content -->

                <div class="ci-ct tnContent">


                    <!-- Check List -->
                    <ul class="check-list">

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197189" type="checkbox" id="checkk197189" >
                                <label for="checkk197189"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-12">

                                  Episode 12

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 07 Jul, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197139" type="checkbox" id="checkk197139" >
                                <label for="checkk197139"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-11">

                                  Episode 11

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 30 Jun, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197095" type="checkbox" id="checkk197095" >
                                <label for="checkk197095"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-10">

                                  Episode 10

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 23 Jun, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="197037" type="checkbox" id="checkk197037" >
                                <label for="checkk197037"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-9">

                                  Episode 9

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 16 Jun, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196976" type="checkbox" id="checkk196976" >
                                <label for="checkk196976"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-8">

                                  Episode 8

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 10 Jun, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196812" type="checkbox" id="checkk196812" >
                                <label for="checkk196812"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-7">

                                  Episode 7

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 19 May, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196742" type="checkbox" id="checkk196742" >
                                <label for="checkk196742"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-6">

                                  Episode 6

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 12 May, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196686" type="checkbox" id="checkk196686" >
                                <label for="checkk196686"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-5">

                                  Episode 5

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 05 May, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196633" type="checkbox" id="checkk196633" >
                                <label for="checkk196633"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-4">

                                  Episode 4

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 28 Apr, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196577" type="checkbox" id="checkk196577" >
                                <label for="checkk196577"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-3">

                                  Episode 3

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 21 Apr, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196516" type="checkbox" id="checkk196516" >
                                <label for="checkk196516"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-2">

                                  Episode 2

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 14 Apr, 2019
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="epCheck ">
                                <input class="act-watched" data-episodeid="196415" type="checkbox" id="checkk196415" >
                                <label for="checkk196415"></label>
                            </div>
                            <a href="https://www.gogoanime1.com/watch/hachigatsu-no-cinderella-nine/episode/episode-1">

                                  Episode 1

                            </a>
                            <br>
                            Released on 07 Apr, 2019
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <!-- Check List -->
```

I want to skip the first "check-list" class and go to the second, then get every

element or  element into a separate list.

Comment: Can you specify a sample format with some dummy data of the required output?

Comment: @10101010 The required data is a list: List animedata=[,name2,name3....]

Comment: I am guessing you are not trying to run this parsing code inside of a flutter app.

Comment: I am fetching the html using an http request inside a flutter app

Comment: By name are you referring to the content inside the a tag(e.g Episode 8)?

Comment: Thanks for the help but it appeared that the website I am using is not the correct one, now I will be trying to implement seleinium or something like it in flutter since the new website I am picking is pretty dynamic